# Create a room ID on the server side and join the client to it using sockets.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I would like to create a random room ID on the server side and emit it to the client on connect, like below:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var roomID = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 13);  
    io.emit('message', roomID);
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) { 
        socket.join(room); 
    })
});
```

Then, once the client has the server-created room ID, I would like to join the client to that room.

```
 var socket = io.connect();
 var lobby;
 socket.on('message', function (data) {
    lobby=data;
 });

 socket.emit('subscribe', lobby);
```

The problem is that I'm not able to pull the `lobby` variable out of the `socket.on()` function. Which, if I understand correctly, is because it's inside the anonymous function, and that makes it asynchronous.

Is there any solution here, or am I stuck with joining a room by giving it a name on the client side?

**Update: based on the first answer, I updated my code.**

Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
var roomID = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 13);  
io.emit('message', roomID);
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) { 
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room); 
        console.log(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms);
 })
});
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('message', function (lobby) {
  $('#msg').val(lobby);
  socket.emit('subscribe', lobby);
});
```

Output (one browser session):

```
joining room bugs69q9znr
{ TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length:
1 },
  bugs69q9znr: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length: 1 } }
```

Output (two browser sessions):

```
joining room c8p8gioeca0
{ TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length:
1 },
  bugs69q9znr: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length: 1 },
  HDWyB6JXsB1rf3PdAAAB: Room { sockets: { HDWyB6JXsB1rf3PdAAAB: true }, length:
1 },
  c8p8gioeca0: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length: 1 } }
joining room c8p8gioeca0
{ TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length:
1 },
  bugs69q9znr: Room { sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true }, length: 1 },
  HDWyB6JXsB1rf3PdAAAB: Room { sockets: { HDWyB6JXsB1rf3PdAAAB: true }, length:
1 },
  c8p8gioeca0:
   Room {
     sockets: { TO1D6tBPU1TebZIPAAAA: true, HDWyB6JXsB1rf3PdAAAB: true },
     length: 2 } }
```

Why is it joining both sockets to my second room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't join the room until you know what lobby you want to join.

```
 var socket = io.connect();
 socket.on('message', function (lobby) {
   socket.emit('subscribe', lobby);
 });
```

Be cautious about this as well... depending on how you're handling things server-side, any client can connect to whatever lobby they want.

Comment: When I do it this way, it joins any new browser session to its own random room plus any rooms created before it.

Comment: @Dshiz It's only going to join what you tell it to join.

Comment: I must have something wrong on the server side, then..  I will give this a try and see if I can find out why my server-side code isn't working as expected.

Comment: I've updated my post with full code and output to show my problem.. As you can see, the second browser session adds both sockets to the second room.

Comment: @Dshiz You're emitting the message to all connected clients.  If you only want them to join one thing, don't use `io.emit`, use `socket.emit` on the server.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you so much